# Load 3D model coming from api in native android app

Tags: api, model, 3d, native

How can I load **3D model** coming from **api** in native android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it from api, you can have .mtl or .obj file from parsing & save it locally.

you can use Rajawali library sample code is :https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali